# How to generate a random hexadecimal string in Julia

Tags: cryptography, hex, julia

I am trying to generate a random hexadecimal string for a blockchain wallet application but I am not sure how I would do it in Julia. In Python, I would do something like

```py
import os
from ecdsa import SigningKey, VerifyingKey, SECP256k1
seed = os.urandom(SECP256k1.baselen)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`randstring`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Random.randstring) specifying the allowed characters:

```
julia> using Random

# default length is 8 characters
julia> randstring(['0':'9'; 'a':'f'])
"e7e15070"

# other custom lengths
julia> randstring(['0':'9'; 'a':'f'], 4)
"9a6a"

julia> randstring(['0':'9'; 'a':'f'], 12)
"df398edb1937"
```

Alternatively you can use [`rand`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Base.rand) + [`bytes2hex`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/#Base.bytes2hex):

```
julia> bytes2hex(rand(UInt8, 4))
"9fae741a"
```

`rand` and `randstring` use by default a [`MersenneTwister`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Random.MersenneTwister) pseudorandom number generator.  If you want to use different streams of random numbers you can use [`RandomDevice`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Random.RandomDevice) instead:

```
julia> randstring(RandomDevice(), ['0':'9'; 'a':'f'])
"6f4499e3"

julia> bytes2hex(rand(RandomDevice(), UInt8, 4))
"4d1c035c"
```

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning [RandomDevice](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Random.RandomDevice), and [bytes2hex](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/#Base.bytes2hex). For example: `bytes2hex(rand(RandomDevice(), UInt8, 12))`

Comment: `randstring` seems completely undescribed, but I'm glad it seems to work. However, I would like the API to specify which random number generator is used. It seems `GLOBAL_RAND`, but I'd explicitly use `RandomDevice()` instead (as first parameter, it seems).

Answer (score 0):

As [stated in the documentation of the standard library](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/index.html#Random.RandomDevice):

> Julia also provides the `RandomDevice` RNG type, which is a wrapper over the OS provided entropy.

Note that the word "entropy" is abused here. The OS will - with high likelihood - not directly return entropy, it will return random bytes from it's own seeded pseudo random number generator.

Comment: Note that this returns a **binary** string or byte array, not a *hexadecimal string*, which is a textual representation of the binary string. I left it out as I don't see it in your Python code either.

Comment: How do I actually use it? When I do `julia> RandomDevice()
RandomDevice(true)` It does not help and passing in strings or ints gives an error.

Comment: `RandomDevice` is not available? What do you mean with "does not help"? Because that's not a helpful error description.